# SQLITE3 not creating database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

It should create the database, but it does not. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by *"it's not creating the database"*? Do you mean the database file or the database file's content? What kind of database do you expect? You need to specify what your database looks like rows, columns, names, etc..., etc...

Comment: check your current working directory, i bet it's there

Comment: There are 2 outcomes of executing this code: 1. The file is not created and you are getting an error. In this case, post this error. 2. The file is created but not where you expect it. Add `import os ; print(os.getcwd())` That is where the file is created

Comment: Beware, the *current* directory may not be what you expect, mainly if you use an IDE... You really should set it with `os.chdir(...)` or at least control it with `os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 2):

This code will create an sqlite db file called "test.db" in the same directory you are running your script from.

For example, if you have your python file in:

```
/home/user/python_code/mycode.py
```

And you run it from:

```
/home/user/
```

With:

```
python python_code/mycode.py # or python3
```

It will create an "empty" sqlite db file at

```
/home/user/test.db
```

If you can't find the test.db file, make sure you pass it the *full path* of where you want it to be located.

i.e.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("/full/path/to/location/you/want/test.db")
```

Comment: Well, looks like the DB is being created but not on current directory. I can access the DB, but can't see it even when checking to see hidden files.

Comment: @AdautoPinheiro are you running the python script as a certain user? Maybe the user that you're using to look for the db does not have permissions to see the file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my .db file wasn't appearing because I forgot to add test.db at the end of path, see line 2 below

```
import sqlite3
databaseFile = "/home/user/test.db" #don't forget the test.db
conn = sqlite3.connect(databaseFile)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the DB will not be created on disk until you create at least one table in it. Just calling `conn.cursor()` is not sufficient.

Console `sqlite3` utility behaves this way, too.

Comment: I just tested and at least in python 3.6.5 it creates the db file.